# Gradient descent algorithm explanation

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

How do I get from the derivative in the second last line to get x<sub>j</sub> in the last line?

[image: Gradient Descent Algorithm]

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} h_\theta(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} [\theta_0 x_0 + \dots + \theta_j x_j + \dots + \theta_n x_n] = 0 + \dots + x_j + \dots + 0
$$
The underlying assumption here is that: $\frac{\partial \theta_i}{ \partial \theta_j }= 0 \ \forall i \neq j$.